# Parsing structured but non-tabular text into pandas using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing

I am trying to parse the following data into pandas from a text file:

```
genome Bacteroidetes_4
reference B650
source carotenoid

genome Desulfovibrio_3
reference B123
source Polyketide
reference B839
source flexirubin
```

I'd like the output to like like this:

```
genome,reference,source
Bacteroidetes_4,B650,carotenoid
Desulfovibrio_3,B123,Polyketide
Desulfovibrio_3,B839,flexirubin
```

I have adapted some code (https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ by Vipin Ajayakumar)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# write regular expressions
rx_dict = {
    'genome': re.compile(r'genome (?P<genome>.*)\n'),
    'source': re.compile(r'source (?P<source>.*)\n'),
    'reference': re.compile(r'reference (?P<reference>.*)\n'),
}

# line parser
def parse_line(line):
    for key, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None
```

I believe there is a problem in the file parser, somewhere in the while loop.

```
def parse_file(filepath):    
    data = []  
    # open the file and read through it line by line
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:        
        line = file_object.readline()        
        while line:           
            # at each line check for a match with a regex
            key, match = parse_line(line)

            # extract from each line
            if key == 'genome':
                genome = match.group('genome')
            if key == 'Source':
                Source = match.group('Source')               
            if key == 'reference':
                Type = match.group('reference')

                while line.strip():
                    row = {
                        'genome': genome,
                        'reference': reference,
                        'Source': Source,
                        }
                    data.append(row)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return data
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = '/path/file.txt'
    data = parse_file(filepath)
    data.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

When I run this code it returns continuously without ending.
Any tips for how to correct or trouble shoot this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is when reading the file here

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:        
    line = file_object.readline()        
    while line:
```

The value of line never changes so the while loop keeps running endlessly

Change to this:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object: 
    lines = file_object.readlines()
    for line in lines:
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and solved that. 
But It now produces an empty dataframe, which is something I saw happen while troubleshooting before. I will update the question.

Comment: I have updated the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496527/parsing-text-into-pandas-using-regular-expressions-but-empty-dataframe-produced

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting breakpoints in the while loop and using the debugger to see what's going on?

You can just use:

```
breakpoint()
```

With Python >= 3.7. For older versions:

```
import pdb

# your code

# for each part you are
# interested in the while 
# loop:
pdb.set_trace()
```

Then run your script with the debugger enabled:

```
>>> python3 -m pdb yourscript.py
```

Use 'c' to continue to the next breakpoint. Fore more information on the commands, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

You could also use an integrated debugger if you use an IDE which has one, which can be less cumbersome to use.

By the way, it is probably because you use `while line` and then never seem to read a new line, so as long as the first line is not an empty string that statements evaluates to True and stays in the while loop indefinitely. You could try iterating over the file with a for loop instead.

E.g.

```
with open('file.suffix', 'r') as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
        # your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

using pandas only, we can use `str.split`

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt',sep='|',header=None)
s = df[0].str.split(' ',expand=True)

df_new = s.set_index([0,s.groupby(0).cumcount()]).unstack(0)
```

---

```
print(df_new)

                 1                      
0           genome reference      source
0  Bacteroidetes_4      B650  carotenoid
1  Desulfovibrio_3      B123  Polyketide
2              NaN      B839  flexirubin
```